# Finding the first non-repeating character javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I tried to solve the problem below on a site, but they keep saying that something is not right when I reach certain tests.

Given a string s consisting of small English letters, find and return the first instance of a non-repeating character in it. If there is no such character, return "_".

I tried this

```
function firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s) {
    let strArr = s.replace(" ", "").split(""),
        newArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        newArr = strArr.filter(lol => lol === strArr[i]);
        if (newArr.length === 1) {
            return newArr[0];  
        };
    };
    return "_";
};
console.log(firstNotRepeatingCharacter("abacabad"));
```

It works for 16 out of 19 tests. why not all

Comment: Do you need to check for a null parameter?

Comment: no, I was just hoping it works since deleting a console.log passed me two more tests.

Comment: Perhaps the tests you failed had spaces? `aa aa` should return ` ` (a space), right?  Is a space a character?  Or, on the other hand, maybe there were other _characters_ besides a space that were not eligible to be detected as non-repeating.  e.g. numerical digits or punctuation or other whitespace characters?

Comment: @Wyck no they should return "i", "_", "b" but these three returned undefined

Comment: What were the inputs to the test cases that failed?

Comment: @Wyck a comment is too long for a single one of them. do you have a CodeSignal acc?

Comment: You're telling me that the values of `s` for the three failing cases are too long to edit into your question?!  What was its length?

Comment: I used console.log("input".length); It outputted 1000 but its "letters..." so I think It's 1000+ letters as input for each test

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all!
I've found an answer.

```js
function firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s) {
    let strArr = s.replace(" ", "").split("");
    for (let str of strArr) 
        if(strArr.indexOf(str) == strArr.lastIndexOf(str))
            return str;
        
    return "_";
};
console.log(firstNotRepeatingCharacter("abacabad"));
```

Comment: I realize this is your own answer, but it doesn't answer the question you asked, which was literally: "...why not all"  Why does the original code only pass 16 of 19 tests, but presumably this passes all 19?

Comment: what do you need `strArr` for? And that `.replace()`? And using a `Set()` you would check every distinct character only once. `for (let char of new Set(s)) if (s.indexOf(char) === s.lastIndexOf(char)) return char;`

Comment: @Wyck yes this solution passed all of them.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks very much I'll certainly learn more about Set()

Answer (score 1):

another approach with a better time complexity:

```js
function firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s) {
  const seenBefore = new Set();
  let result = "_";
  for (let i = s.length; i--;) {
    const char = s.charAt(i);
    if (seenBefore.has(char)) continue;
    seenBefore.add(char);
    result = char;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(firstNotRepeatingCharacter("abacabad"));
```

Comment: I've just checked this solution it only passed 11 out of 19